# tikzpicture to create a first page with an image in background taking the whole page

Tags: tikz-pgf, environments

I am trying to create a newsletter with Latex, but I am not expert at all. My goal is, for the moment, to create a first page (the cover), with an image in the background, and some text overprinted. Looking around this SE, I found the `tikzpicture` as a possible environment for this purpose. Copying and pasting here and there, I came out with a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,bmargin=3cm,tmargin=4.5cm,centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{LiberGMA.eps}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\pagestyle{empty}
%\AtBeginShipout{\Header\Footer} # comments are where the line is in the code from which I copied, but I don't know the meaning
%\AtBeginShipoutFirst{\Header\Footer} 


\begin{multicols}{2}
%\lipsum[1-15]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Now, it happens that I want the image to take all the first page, but I have to set the size, and after a certain size, the image is moved in the second page, leaving the first blank. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To include a big image without creating a new page, you may add `remember picture` and `overlay` options to your `tikzpicture` environment.

To anchor your picture to the corner of the page, you may use the special node `current page` (p. 250 of pgfmanual v3.0.0).

Example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,bmargin=3cm,tmargin=4.5cm,centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0,text opacity=.5]
  (image) at (current page.south west)
  {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[4-10]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to work very well, thanks! Could you please just tell me what the "text opacity=.5" do? I guess it works on the transparency. So, how to set it to make the text overprinted?

Comment: @Py-ser For TikZ, the content of a node is a "text". With `text opacity=.5`, the big image is semi-transparent and we can read the overprinted text.

Comment: thanks, but I don't want the image became transparent. The text must be overprinted, not in the background. The image is in the background. I am sorry for not being able to express it technically, I hope it is clear enough.

Comment: Besides, the image in the first page, is cut at the bottom.

Comment: @Py-ser The text (lipsum) is not in the background... but a black text over a black image is unreadable. With `text opacity`, the black image is overprinted transparently over the white background and thus the image seems gray.

Comment: @Py-ser The `remember picture` option and the special node `current page` require two compilations to get the correct location.

Comment: so that is specific only for black images ? Btw, I always compile three times by default :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15420/discussion-between-paul-gaborit-and-py-ser).

Answer (score 3):

A second alternative is the use of `background` package. Here `BackGroundImage` macro taking 2 arguments is defined to add a background image.

**Edit:** If keeping the aspectratio is desired, then modify the macro a little bit, as shown below.

```
\newcommand\BackGroundImage[2][1]{% the default value is one
\BgThispage
\backgroundsetup{
contents={\includegraphics [width=#1\paperwidth, height=#1\paperheight, keepaspectratio] {#2}}
 }
}
```

and execute it as

```
\BackGroundImage[2]{example-image-a}  % magnified by 2
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,bmargin=3cm,tmargin=4.5cm,centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[pages=some,scale=1,angle=0,opacity=0.7]{background}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\newcommand\BackGroundImage[2][scale=1]{%
\BgThispage
\backgroundsetup{
  contents={\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\BackGroundImage[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}% image on page 1
\begin{multicols}{2}

\lipsum[2]

\lipsum[4-10]

\lipsum[4-10]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```